# How to display date time in jquery count down clock?

Tags: jquery, date, datetime

I have a database attribute "deadline" whose data type is date time in format `"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"`, requirement is to get date time from data base and pass it in count down clock which will show days, hours, minutes and seconds remaining. I go through these links: [link1](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html) and [link2](http://flipclockjs.com/). And take code from link1. Include all files, but no count down clock is visible on browser. here is code:

```
<html>
<head>


    <title>Index</title>
    <link href="~/Content/jquery.countdown.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.countdown.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        #defaultCountdown {
            width: 240px;
            height: 45px;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.plugin.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.plugin.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.countdown.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(function () {
                var austDay = new Date();
                austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 26);
                $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({ until: austDay });
                $('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
            });
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="defaultCountdown"></div>

            <p>Counting down to 26 January <span id="year">2014</span>.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Can any one please tell why this clock is not visible on browser and how can I achieve my above mention requirement? 
Code will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Works for me -> **http://jsfiddle.net/uarajn1f/**

Comment: You've added `plugin.js` twice BTW

Comment: @adeneo nothing works here. I am working on VS 2013, Firefox browser. It can be a browser compatibility issue ? I have an error on my browser console: "TypeError:$.JQPlugin is undefined" jquery.countdown.js line:28,col:1